# Angular $routeParams force variable type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, casting, route-provider

In my Angular app, I have routes like `/items/:id`

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/items/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    })
```

In ItemCtrl I get `:id` with `$routeParams.parcId` The problem is it's a string while the value is a number and all my id are numbers.

So how to force the correct type and not having string by default?

ps: I don't want to do `var id = Number($routeParams.parcId)` in all my controllers

Comment: `var id = parseFloat($routeParams.parcId);` ?

Comment: Like I said, I want to avoid code in controllers

Comment: Up-voted this question, I have the same problem.

Comment: I can only suggest to use $routeProvider wrapper like 
ui-router, it supports having [typed params](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the **$routeChangeStart** event.

In your app.js file, add the following line to the .run function as :-

```
angular.module('test1App').run(function ($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

    if (next.params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
      next.params.id = Number(next.params.id);
    }

  });

});
```

Description: On every change of route, it checks if there is a parameter named 'id'. If yes then it changes it to a number.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Have not tried this, but for me this looks correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use resolve in routes and update the variable. Then use this resolved variable in controller

```
<a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/2nXeY325ouqyFtJTLcdq?p=preview"> Example </a>
```

Answer (score -3):

did you try like this?

```
parseInt($routeParams.parcId)
```